# How to get all keys out of associative array in php

Tags: php, associative-array

I have an associative array in php. When I am doing a die on it, then I am getting proper values as follows:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [123]=> string(5) "Hello" }}
```

But when I am trying extract out keys of this array into an new array, then I am not able to get keys out:

```
$uniqueIds = array_keys($myAssociativeArray);
die(var_dump($uniqueIds));
int(0) array(1) { [0]=> int(0) }
```

Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong here? I want to get all the keys out of my associative array. And for this, I am referring to thread: [php: how to get associative array key from numeric index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095796/php-how-to-get-associative-array-key-from-numeric-index)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$uniqueIds = array_keys($myAssociativeArray[0]);
```

Comment: It is giving me key. but I want keys for all elements in $myAssociativeArray

Comment: I don't think this is the appropriate answer

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    function multiarray_keys($ar) {

        foreach($ar as $k => $v) {
            $keys[] = $k;
            if (is_array($ar[$k]))
                $keys = array_merge($keys, multiarray_keys($ar[$k]));
        }
        return $keys;
    }
$result = multiarray_keys($myAssociativeArray);
var_dump($result);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following recursively gets all the keys in an associative array

```
function getArrayKeysFlat($array) {
    if(!isset($keys) || !is_array($keys)) {
        $keys = array();
    }
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $keys[] = $key;
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $keys = array_merge($keys,getArrayKeysFlat($value));
        }
    }
    return $keys;
}
```