# get key value from php array with string as key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array with strings as keys and I want to list all the keys and corresponding values in the order in which it was input. For example:

```
$arr=array();
$arr['tree']='leaves';
$arr['fruits']='seed';
```

and output should be like :

keys   : tree, fruits
values : leaves,seed

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

Comment: How do you determine that you want to fetch this specific key? On a whim? Or do you have a specific situation and reason why you need to fetch a specific key?

Comment: Also: [how to get associative array key from numeric index?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4095838/476)

Comment: well i just want to populate the keys in the order in which keys are input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running a version of PHP that supports array dereferencing:

```
$key = array_keys($arr)[1];
```

else

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$key = $keys[1];
```

Comment: Neat :) Side note: Array dereferencing exists since PHP 5.4

Comment: thanks the second code works,direct fetching is showing syntax error

Answer (score 1):

make it associative array you can get both keys and values

```
$arr=array('tree'=>'leaves','fruits'=>'seeds');


foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
{
   echo $key."====>".$value;
}
```