# php- how to push key and value of an array to another array

Tags: php, arrays

I save an array that contains some translation in text file. (.txt)

**array structure :**

```
$translate = array(
  "Search. Discover. Book Instantly" => "بگرد مقایسه کن رزرو کن",
  '24/7 Access to top salon' => ' خیلی خوب خیلی عالی در 7 روز هفته',
  'EASY AND SIMPLE'=> 'راحت و ساده',
);
```

now I want to add new fields to array but I don't know how to do it, I need something like `array_push()` for add keys and value both.

**Example:**

```
$new_line = array("Hello World" => "سلام دنیا");

// add to main array
$translate = array(
  "Search. Discover. Book Instantly" => "بگرد مقایسه کن رزرو کن",
  '24/7 Access to top salon' => ' خیلی خوب خیلی عالی در 7 روز هفته',
  'EASY AND SIMPLE'=> 'راحت و ساده',
  "Hello World" => "سلام دنیا"
);
```

Comment: You can do some this like this ```$translate['Hello World'] = "سلام دنیا";```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since `$new_line` is an array, you probably want to merge them

```
array_merge($array1, $array2)
```

> read more here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$translate = array(
  "Search. Discover. Book Instantly" => "بگرد مقایسه کن رزرو کن",
  '24/7 Access to top salon' => ' خیلی خوب خیلی عالی در 7 روز هفته',
  'EASY AND SIMPLE'=> 'راحت و ساده'
); 

$translate["Hello World"] = "سلام دنیا";
```

Or if you have a separate array with new values

```
$new_line = array("Hello World" => "سلام دنیا", "Hello World1" => "سلام دنیا");

$translate = array_merge($translate, $new_line);
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the same as an array push

```
$translate[] = [
    'Hello World' => 'سلام دنیا'
];
```

Comment: You should note that this will work on php 7. Earlier version use array() instead of []

Comment: Thanks @JurijJazdanov your right, my mistake for assuming PHP version. all good, RiggsFolly is gonna get the top answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like that

```
$translate['Hello World'] = "سلام دنیا";
```

There is no array_push() equivalent for associative arrays because there is no way determine the next key.

Comment: No you have to specify key and there value. $translate['key'] = "value";

Comment: that's not true. It will use the key as a number and increment it. Please don't misinform if you are not sure

Comment: you are assuming that $translate[] = 'value' wont work. That's incorrect and it is a equivalent to array_push(), which u said is not.

Comment: I mentioned  **$translate['key'] = "value"** @JurijJazdanov

Answer (score 0):

simply add a new entry

```
<?php

$new = array("Hello World" => "سلام دنیا");

// add to main array
$translate = array(
  "Search. Discover. Book Instantly" => "بگرد مقایسه کن رزرو کن",
  '24/7 Access to top salon' => ' خیلی خوب خیلی عالی در 7 روز هفته',
  'EASY AND SIMPLE'=> 'راحت و ساده',
  "Hello World" => "سلام دنیا"
); 

/* single entry * /
$translate['new'] = $new[0];
unset($new[0]);
/**/

//several entries
//array_merge($translate,$new);

//or with iteration
foreach($new as $k => $v){
    //here you could add some conditions on what to add and what not
    $translate[$k]=$v;
    unset($new[$k]);
};

print_r( $translate );

?>
```

maybe you do not need unset. also have a look at [find the key for associative array entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095796/php-how-to-get-associative-array-key-from-numeric-index).

Answer (score 0):

With the use of the `key()` array function it can be done like this.

```
$translate = array(
  "Search. Discover. Book Instantly" => "بگرد مقایسه کن رزرو کن",
  '24/7 Access to top salon' => ' خیلی خوب خیلی عالی در 7 روز هفته',
  'EASY AND SIMPLE'=> 'راحت و ساده',
); 

$new_line = array("Hello World" => "سلام دنیا");

$translate[key($new_line)] = $new_line[key($new_line)];

print_r($translate);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [Search. Discover. Book Instantly] => بگرد مقایسه کن رزرو کن
    [24/7 Access to top salon] =>  خیلی خوب خیلی عالی در 7 روز هفته
    [EASY AND SIMPLE] => راحت و ساده
    [Hello World] => سلام دنیا
)
```