# Access PHP array of strings by index

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array like

```
$arr = array("c_m_email" => "a@b.z");
```

and I can access the email by

```
$arr['c_m_email']
```

But is there another way to just write `$arr[0]`?

Comment: No, an array value has one key and that is the only key you can use.

Comment: No, because the index is `'c_m_email'` and not `0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php: how to get associative array key from numeric index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095796/php-how-to-get-associative-array-key-from-numeric-index)

Comment: If you want to use [0] than you have to edit that array and set index from [c_m_email] to [0]. Otherwise you have to use [c_m_email].

Comment: All those comments aren't true! Use ```array_values()``` as modsfabio said in the answer below and you can access the elements by their index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `array_values()`

> **array_values()** returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first entry in the array, you could also do this:

```
reset($h);
echo current($h)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $i=0;
    $data=array();

   foreach($arr as $value){

       $data[$i] = $value;

       $i++;

    }

    print_r($data);
```

Comment: This is exactly what the PHP function `array_values()` does. So, why would you write the code for that by yourself?

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.